# Definite Integration with limits

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Let

$$I_n := \int\limits_0^1 x^n\sqrt{1-x^2} \,\mathrm d x$$

What is the following limit equal to?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{I_n}{I_{n-2}}$$

I tried using the integration by parts method, but couldn't come to any final answer.

Comment: Your integral is equal to $$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{\sqrt{\pi }
   \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{4 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n}{2}+2\right)},\Re(n)>-1\right]$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Set $x=\sin t,dx=\cos t\ dt$

$$I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^nt\cos^2t\ dt=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^nt(1-\sin^2t)\ dt=J_n-J_{n+2}$$

where $\displaystyle J_m=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^mt\ dt$

Use [this](http://www.vias.org/calculus/07_trigonometric_functions_05_03.html) to find $$J_m=\dfrac{m-1}mJ_{m-2}$$

$I_n=J_n-J_{n+2}=J_n-\dfrac{m-1}{m+2}J_n=\dfrac{3J_n}{m+2}$

$I_{n-2}=?$

Answer (score 1):

Integrate by parts $u=x^{n-1}, dv = x\sqrt{1-x^2}\;dx$.  I chose this because I can easily integrate $dv$.  Then we get
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\!{x}^{n}\sqrt {1-x^2}\,{\rm d}x=-\frac{n-1}{3}
\int_{0}^{1}\,
{ {{x}^{n-2}  (x^2-1) \sqrt {1-x^2}}}\,{\rm d}x
$$
Tne right-hand-side is a linear combination of $I_n$ and $I_{n-2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:
$$\begin{align}I_n &= \int\limits_0^1 x^n\sqrt{1-x^2} \,\mathrm d x=\\
&= \int\limits_0^1 (1-(x^2-1))x^{n-2}\sqrt{1-x^2} \,\mathrm d x=\\
&=I_{n-2}-\int\limits_0^1 (1-x^2)^{3/2}dx=\\
&=I_{n-2}-\frac{3\pi}{16}.\end{align}$$
Hence:
$$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \frac{I_n}{I_{n-2}}=1.$$

=================================================================

Note:
$$I_0=\frac{\pi}{4},I_1=\frac13.$$
The solution is:
$$I_n = \frac16 ((-1)^{n+1} + 1) + \frac1{64} π (-6 n + 5 (-1)^n + 3 (-1)^{2n} + 8)$$
WA answer: [1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%281-x%5E2%29%5E%283%2F2%29%20from%200%20to%201), [2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%281-x%5E2%29%5E%281%2F2%29%20from%200%20to%201), [3](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20x%281-x%5E2%29%5E%281%2F2%29%20from%200%20to%201), [4](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28n%29%3Df%28n-2%29-%283pi%29%2F16%2Cf%280%29%3Dpi%2F4%2Cf%281%29%3D1%2F3).